# View only 1 element of a webpage

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which is loading a webpage. The webpage has a div-element that I want to view. Nothing else from the webpage, just the div.

Is this possible, and if yes, how ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` method of [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access page elements using JavaScript.

Assuming your div has an id set, you can use the `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML` JavaScript method to access its content.